# Is "NASDAQ to launch etc.." is a right usage?

Tags: usage

I saw this title at a website:

> What Crypto Winter? Nasdaq to Launch Bitcoin Futures Market: Report

It seems to me that there is a problem with this sentence. To my point of view, it should be : Nasaq is launching etc.. 
Is it a different meaning?
There is a role for that? Thanks

Comment: Please include the full sentence in case the context is relevant.

Comment: Not relevant. The question is about this kind of titles. Also "Trump to have new adviser"

Comment: @ascomp  One way or another, this question must have more detail.   The full context would help, such as where you found it.  "Lunch" is probably not the right word ("launch" is more likely), and you haven't explained what you think is wrong about the sentence.  As it is, this question should be closed.

Comment: Ok I Changed it

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. The use of the infinitive to represent a future condition is an example of the English peculiar to news headlines, jocularly known as *headlinese*. See *[Differences in meaning when the verb tense changes (headlines)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672)* and *[Why do we have to use 'to' instead of 'will'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132152/why-do-we-have-to-use-to-instead-of-will)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

News headlines use a particular style of abbreviated syntax which is different to standard spoken or written English. This is not 'incorrect' since it is a very specific style used in journalism.

> "Nasdaq to Launch" = "Nasdaq is going to launch"